# How to implement validation with keyboard done button Flutter, observable, streamBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, rxdart

I'm building an app with Flutter and Bloc like architecture. I'm trying to call submit func with not only login button but also keyboard done button with password; only when email and password are valid.

I could implement login button version with combineLatest, but I'm not sure keyboard version. I need to validate both email and password when keyboard done button pressed before calling submit. I could nest streamBuilder, but I feel it is not good practice.

Is there any way to get the latest value from combineLatest? `BehaviorSubject<bool>().value` Or any possible advice to implement this.

**sample code:**

```
      final _emailController = BehaviorSubject<String>();
      final _passwordController = BehaviorSubject<String>();

      // Add data to stream
      Stream<String> get email => _emailController.stream.transform(validateEmail);
      Stream<String> get password =>
          _passwordController.stream.transform(validatePassword);

      Stream<bool> get submitValid =>
          Observable.combineLatest2(email, password, (e, p) => true);

      // change data
      Function(String) get changeEmail => _emailController.sink.add;
      Function(String) get changePassword => _passwordController.sink.add;

      submit() {
        final validEmail = _emailController.value;
        final validPassword = _passwordController.value;

        print('Email is $validEmail, and password is $validPassword');
      }
```

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import '../blocs/bloc.dart';
    import '../blocs/provider.dart';

    class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final bloc = Provider.of(context);

        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              emailField(bloc),
              passwordField(bloc),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
              ),
              submitButton(bloc),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }

      Widget emailField(Bloc bloc) {
        return StreamBuilder(
          stream: bloc.email,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return TextField(
              onChanged: bloc.changeEmail,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'ypu@example.com',
                labelText: 'Email Address',
                errorText: snapshot.error,
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      }

      Widget passwordField(Bloc bloc) {
        return StreamBuilder(
            stream: bloc.password,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return TextField(
                obscureText: true,
                onChanged: bloc.changePassword,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Password',
                  labelText: 'Password',
                  errorText: snapshot.error,
                ),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                onSubmitted: () {}, // <- here
              );
            });
      }

      Widget submitButton(Bloc bloc) {
        return StreamBuilder(
          stream: bloc.submitValid,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Login'),
              color: Colors.blue,
              onPressed: snapshot.hasData ? bloc.submit : null,
            );
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap Your Password streamBuilder with another streamBilder and onSubmitted call submit method.

```
Widget passwordField(Bloc bloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: bloc.submitValid,
        builder: (context, snap) {
          return StreamBuilder(
        stream: bloc.password,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return TextField(
            obscureText: true,
            onChanged: bloc.changePassword,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Password',
              labelText: 'Password',
              errorText: snapshot.error,
            ),
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
            onSubmitted: snap.hasData ? bloc.submit : null,
          );
        });
     });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand this way, but is there any other way? Maybe nesting is not as bad as I thought

Comment: it is not possible in any other way because you have to call onSubmitted only so you have to follow this way only.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Accept the answer if you found it useful, so other also can get benefit. @user12208004